# How to prevent random produced objects from overlapping? corona sdk

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

[CODE]

```
local buildingsA= getBuildings("level1a")
local buildingsB= getBuildings("level1b")
local buildingsC= getBuildings("level1c")

buildingsA.x=1100
buildingsB.x=buildingsA.x+buildingsA.width+300
buildingsC.x=buildingsB.x+buildingsB.width+350
--END OF LEVEL1 CREATION

timer.performWithDelay(1, function(e)
    buildingsA.x = buildingsA.x -15
    buildingsB.x = buildingsB.x-15
    buildingsC.x = buildingsC.x-15
    end, 0 )    

function scrollblocks(self, event)
    if self.x <-100 then
        self.x=math.random(1200,2000) 
    end
end
buildingsA.enterFrame= scrollblocks
buildingsB.enterFrame= scrollblocks
buildingsC.enterFrame= scrollblocks

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", buildingsA)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", buildingsB)
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", buildingsC)

--Add hole
local hole = display.newImage("hole.png", true)
    physics.addBody(hole, "static", {friction= 0.5, bounce=0})
    hole.y=floor_bottom.y-60
    hole.x= buildingsA.x+100

timer.performWithDelay(1, function(e) 
    hole.x= hole.x-15 
    end, 0 )    

hole.enterFrame=scrollblocks
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", hole)
```

[/CODE]

I first produced the buildings and then made them move to the left slowly, and produced random ones from the right side of the screen so as to appear as a loop,buildings left and appear from the right.
I do the same with the holes but they appear to overlap with the buildings. 
How do i restrict them from overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `object:toFront()` or `object:toBack()` to change the Display Hierarchy or you can change it by setting an index number to the display Group like for example:

```
 displayGroup = display.newGroup()
 object1 = display.newImage("img1.png")
 object2 = display.newImage("img2.png")
 object3 = display.newImage("img3.png")

--inserting object to display group using index
 group:insert(1,object1)
 group:insert(2,object2)
 group:insert(3,object3)
```